# mysql match by date using date_sub

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql query

```
SELECT *
FROM
  all_sent_Orders a
WHERE
  a.nachforschungCompletedOn IS NULL AND
  CASE WHEN a.lastMessageSent IS NOT NULL AND a.lastResponse IS NULL
    THEN
      date(date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY)) = date(a.lastMessageSent)
  ELSE
    (date(date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)) = date(IFNULL(a.lastResponse, a.nachforschungSentOn))
     OR date(date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 60 DAY)) = date(IFNULL(a.lastResponse, a.nachforschungSentOn))
     OR date(date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 90 DAY)) = date(IFNULL(a.lastResponse, a.nachforschungSentOn))
     OR date(date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 120 DAY)) = date(IFNULL(a.lastResponse, a.nachforschungSentOn)))
  END
```

What bothers me is the part starting from `ELSE`. I need to find all entries that are `today - 30,60,90,120,150,... days`. Is there a way to rewrite the many OR's to a single expression, matching the same?

I was thinking of a loop, but that will only work in a procedure. I'd like to avoid that, but would be ok with it if there's no alternative.

Comment: You should better post your table layout and ask about the desired outcome, rather than posting an expected solution and ask how to fix it. (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'm not asking how to fix it, it works perfectly fine. I just want to avoid 10 `OR`s @dognose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your comments and update, I believe what you need is `HAVING` rather than `WHERE`. (*Not true, see end of the post, both work in this case.)

So, something along the lines should be what simplifies your query as required:

Consider the data-set:

```
INSERT INTO test2 (id, lastMessageSent, lastResponse, nachforschungSentOn)VALUES(1, date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY), NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO test2 (id, lastMessageSent, lastResponse, nachforschungSentOn)VALUES(2, date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 DAY), date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY), NULL);
INSERT INTO test2 (id, lastMessageSent, lastResponse, nachforschungSentOn)VALUES(3, null, null, date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY));

INSERT INTO test2 (id, lastMessageSent, lastResponse, nachforschungSentOn)VALUES(4, date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 29 DAY), NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO test2 (id, lastMessageSent, lastResponse, nachforschungSentOn)VALUES(5, date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 DAY), date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 59 DAY), NULL);
INSERT INTO test2 (id, lastMessageSent, lastResponse, nachforschungSentOn)VALUES(6, null,null , date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 89 DAY));
```

Which would produce the following set of data:

[image]

and using the following query on `2017-02-14`:

```
SELECT 
   a.* , 
   COALESCE( a.lastResponse, COALESCE( a.lastMessageSent, a.nachforschungSentOn ) ) AS relevantDate, 
   DATEDIFF( NOW( ) , COALESCE( a.lastResponse, COALESCE( a.lastMessageSent, a.nachforschungSentOn ) ) ) AS age
FROM 
  test2 a
HAVING 
  age
IN ( 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180 )
```

would yield the following result, cause id 4,5,6 do not match on multiples of 30 days (See second screenshot without having-clause):

[image]

[image]

Would that be about your expectation? (If the order of date-precedence does not "match", just change them as required or add min/max, if the null-thingy is wrong :) )

Edit:

Using `where` it should work as well, cause there is no `group by`. 
Both should be almost equal in performance, cause there is no `join` in the query. (If joins are present it is better to use `WHERE` over `HAVING` (if possible at all: `where` does not work on aggregated data) cause it minimizes the join-result)

```
SELECT 
   a.* , 
   COALESCE( a.lastResponse, COALESCE( a.lastMessageSent, a.nachforschungSentOn ) ) AS relevantDate, 
   DATEDIFF( NOW( ) , COALESCE( a.lastResponse, COALESCE( a.lastMessageSent, a.nachforschungSentOn ) ) ) AS age
FROM 
  test2 a
WHERE
  DATEDIFF( NOW( ) , COALESCE( a.lastResponse, COALESCE( a.lastMessageSent, a.nachforschungSentOn ) ) )
IN ( 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180 )
```

pps.: As you can see - there is no `date_sub` in the solution - so your question was exactly a case of the XY-Problem as outlined in the first comment - just because you thought `date_sub` can solve this. :P

Comment: Added an extra +1 for your pps :P Thanks a lot, that's amazing!

Comment: Oh, but it doesn't take into account that `lastMessageSent` may be only 7 days, but I can add this to your query.

Comment: @Michael you're welcome :) It's not copy/paste code, but from what you got already I assume you can modify it as required.

Answer (score 0):

The Day() function can be used here to compare the day of the month for today's date with the date provided, which I think does what you are looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  all_sent_Orders a
WHERE
  a.nachforschungCompletedOn IS NULL AND
  CASE WHEN a.lastMessageSent IS NOT NULL AND a.lastResponse IS NULL
    THEN
      date(date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) = date(a.lastMessageSent)
  ELSE
    day(date(current_date)) = day(date(IFNULL(a.lastResponse, a.nachforschungSentOn)))
  END
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought about that too, but it will fail if the entry is made on 31-01-2017 and the check runs on 28-02-2017 --- so it would only be true one month too late on 31-03-2017

Comment: @Michael that's what my comment is/was about :-) It is somewhat unclear what's the desired outcome. So, it seems like you want to have entries which are EXACTLY 1,2,3... months old - none with 29 or 31 days (if that month has 30 days?) What is with entries made on 31.01 when queried on 29th feb / 2nd march?

Comment: Sorry, @dognose you got me... :-) I've edited the question accordingly to subtract days.

Comment: How about something like this? `(dayofyear(date(current_date)) - dayofyear(date(IFNULL(a.lastResponse, a.nachforschungSentOn))))%30 = 0`